# Bar Chart - Change Face Color Separately For Every Single Bar

Tags: bar-chart, matlab, matlab2tikz

I am using `Matlab`'s `bar` command to create a bar-chart. I am using `matlab2tikz` to convert it. I would like to change the face color of every single bar separately to an rgb color of my choice. In `Matlab` I can do so by using this code:

b = bar(x,y,'FaceColor','flat')
b.CData(2,:) = [1 0 0];
b.CData(3,:) = [0 1 0];
b.CData(4,:) = [0 0 1];
b.CData(5,:) = [0 0 0];
b.CData(6,:) = [1 0 1];

However this results in all transparent bars in my `texfile`, which goes as follows:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.729in,
height=2.325in,
at={(0.793in,0.498in)},
scale only axis,
bar shift auto,
xmin=0,
xmax=7,
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6},
xticklabels={{},{t = 3,0},{t = 3,5 s},{t = 4,0 s},{t = 5,0 s},{t \( \approx \) 30 s}},
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={Messreihennummer},
ymin=0,
ymax=160,
ytick={  0,  20,  40,  60,  80, 100, 120, 140, 160},
yminorticks=true,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Kan\"ulenauszugskraft in N},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
xminorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
yminorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black},
legend style={},
]
\addplot[ybar, bar width=0.8, fill=mycolor1, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
1   0\\
2   49.2731776918684\\
3   55.5745267232259\\
4   60.3699144999186\\
5   91.1499318440755\\
6   150.601191206667\\
};
\addplot[forget plot, color=white!15!black] table[row sep=crcr] {%
0   0\\
7   0\\
};
\addlegendentry{Probe 1}

\addplot [color=black, line width=2.0pt, draw=none]
 plot [error bars/.cd, y dir = both, y explicit]
 table[row sep=crcr, y error plus index=2, y error minus index=3]{%
1   0   0   0\\
2   49.2731776918684    19.964130020244 19.964130020244\\
3   55.5745267232259    15.9911247772533    15.9911247772533\\
4   60.3699144999186    7.89742116804573    7.89742116804573\\
5   91.1499318440755    13.3824237377185    13.3824237377185\\
6   150.601191206667    2.13783749065102    2.13783749065102\\
};
\addlegendentry{Probe 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

The following line is the one which creates the bars:

```
\addplot[ybar, bar width=0.8, fill=mycolor1, draw=black, area legend] table[row sep=crcr] {%
```

Using mycolor1 from the line at the top:

```
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

I would like to adjust the texfile in a way where I'll get the face colors I want as a result. This can be done by using a different Matlab code or adjusting the texfile via Matlab as in:

```
    matlab2tikz('Uebersicht_Nadelauszugskraefte.tikz',...
        'extraaxisoptions',['legend style={legend columns=5},',...
        'legend style={font=\tiny},'])
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

How about a direct way with TikZ (instead of `mathlab2tikz`)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.5mm,x=1.5cm]
\draw[gray!50,local bounding box=L] (0,0) grid[xstep=1.5cm,ystep=20] (7,160);
\foreach \i/\ione/\itwo/\itext in
{1/0/0/,
2/49.2731776918684/19.964130020244/t=3.0,
3/55.5745267232259/15.9911247772533/t=3.5,
4/60.3699144999186/7.89742116804573/t=4.0,
5/91.1499318440755/13.3824237377185/t=4.5,
6/150.601191206667/2.13783749065102/t\approx 30
}{
\draw[blue!50,line width=10mm] 
(\i,0) node[below=-5mm,black]{$\itext$}--+(90:\ione) coordinate (tmp);
\draw[red,line width=10mm] (tmp)--+(90:\itwo);
}
\foreach \i in {0,...,8}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(20*\i)}    
\path (0,\j) node[left]{$\j$};
}

\draw (0,0) rectangle (7,160);
\path
(L.west)+(180:1) node[rotate=90]{Kan\"ulenauszugskraft in $N$}
(L.south)+(-90:18) node{Messreihennummer}
;

% legends (as a matrix node)
\path (2,130) node[matrix,draw,fill=white]{
\draw[line width=2mm,blue!50] (0,0)--+(0:.5);&\node{Probe 1};\\
\draw[line width=2mm,red] (0,0)--+(0:.5);&\node{Probe 2};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like an idea. Thank you.
Is it possible to change the face color of the different bars e.g. so one is red? And can you show me in my code above how I could make the adjustment? This would be great!

Comment: @Timon just look for `magenta`s, and replace them by `red` as you want

Comment: @Timon I changed to `red` as you asked.